# Function arguments, object with values equal to an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently working on a MongoDB Javascript developer code.

There is something that I can't wrap my mind around:

This method has some funky business going on in the arguments here. What does `{filters = null, page = 0, moviesPerPage = 20} = {}` mean? What do you achieve by equating it to an empty object?

```
  static async getMovies({
    filters = null,
    page = 0,
    moviesPerPage = 20,
  } = {}) {
   /// more code
...}
```

Here is the entire function for more context should you need it:

```
  static async getMovies({
    filters = null,
    page = 0,
    moviesPerPage = 20,
  } = {}) {
    let queryParams = {}
    if (filters) {
      if ("text" in filters) {
        queryParams = this.textSearchQuery(filters["text"])
      } else if ("cast" in filters) {
        queryParams = this.castSearchQuery(filters["cast"])
      } else if ("genre" in filters) {
        queryParams = this.genreSearchQuery(filters["genre"])
      }
    }

    let { query = {}, project = {}, sort = DEFAULT_SORT } = queryParams
    let cursor
    try {
      cursor = await movies
        .find(query)
        .project(project)
        .sort(sort)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(`Unable to issue find command, ${e}`)
      return { moviesList: [], totalNumMovies: 0 }
    }

    /**
    Ticket: Paging

    Before this method returns back to the API, use the "moviesPerPage" and
    "page" arguments to decide the movies to display.

    Paging can be implemented by using the skip() and limit() cursor methods.
    */

    // TODO Ticket: Paging
    // Use the cursor to only return the movies that belong on the current page
    const displayCursor = cursor.limit(moviesPerPage)

    try {
      const moviesList = await displayCursor.toArray()
      const totalNumMovies = page === 0 ? await movies.countDocuments(query) : 0

      return { moviesList, totalNumMovies }
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(
        `Unable to convert cursor to array or problem counting documents, ${e}`,
      )
      return { moviesList: [], totalNumMovies: 0 }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a default parameter. It prevents the method from throwing an error if the parameter is not provided.

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

```js
function getMovies({
  filters = null,
  page = 0,
  moviesPerPage = 20,
} = {}) {
  console.log('getMovies', filters, page, moviesPerPage)
}

function getMovies2({
  filters = null,
  page = 0,
  moviesPerPage = 20,
}) {
  console.log('getMovies2', filters, page, moviesPerPage)
}

getMovies({})
getMovies()
getMovies2({})
getMovies2()
```

Comment: Isn't throwing an error a good thing? I guess it would depend on the overal design of the application.

Comment: Yeah, it depends. You'd have to call it with an empty object yourself if you wanted to use the default properties: `getMovies({})`

Comment: There is a line further down: `let { query = {}, project = {}, sort = DEFAULT_SORT } = queryParams` follows the same logic? Have that object be empty unless there it is specified in `queryParams`

Comment: Yes. But this could potentially crash if `queryParams` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

It is **default function parameter**.

If when there's not any parameter, the `{}` would be default value of that prop.

This is necessary because if any parameter is not passed, the value becomes `undefined`.

In this case, an error occurs when if you attempting to get values such as `filters` and `page` from the `undefined` prop. so it seems that was used.